# Generating image name with jpg extention in MATLAB using genvarname

Tags: matlab

I want to generate image name to read it later in the matlab code. I have name of the image in the work space as:

```
   ImageName =

   'OECA 2682_001_001'
```

I have done following to generate name and read image:

```
  ext_img='*.jpg';
  varname = genvarname(ImageName,ext_img)
  image = imread('varname');
```

But varname is coming out to be :

```
  varname =

    x0x27OECA2682_001_0010x27
```

instead of OECA 2682_001_001.jpg. I want to read image as:

```
 image=imread('OECA 2682_001_001.jpg');
```

How can I generate name of image with jpg extention to read image. Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's  not how `genvarname` works.  You want to do:

```
varname = [genvarname(ImageName) '.jpg']
```

but I don't think you need `genvarname` at all. [It's used for making a variable name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html), but you are not using it like that.

Also, instead of using

```
image = imread('varname');
```

you want

```
image = imread(varname);
```

Comment: But running the command: varname = [genvarname(ImageName) '.jpg'] is generating: varname = x0x27OECA2682_001_0010x27.jpg. but not as OECA 2682_001_001.jpg.???? Also please note that ImageName in workplace is stored in the form of ''OECA 2682_001_001'' . i.e inside double colons.

Comment: I have used: C =  strrep(ImageName,'''','') %%%%%%%%%%%%%% this make double quotes gone and now C=OECA 2682_001_001 but when I am using  varname=[genvarname(C) '.jpg'] this makes OECA2682_001_001.jpg instead of OECA 2682_001_001.jpg (please note the sapce between OECA and 2682_001_001)

Comment: Don't use `genvarname` and you won't get that weird suffix or the space removed.

Comment: Thanks, varname = [(C) '.jpg']; image = imread(varname); did my job....Thanks once again